# How can I remap one JSON lines to hierachycal JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I am meeting now the difficult problem for me that hurt my heart,
I want to convert [01] JSON to [02].

[01] JSON :

```
{locations: [
    {
        country: "Australia",
        area: "NSW",
        city: "Gordon"
    },
    {
        country: "Australia",
        area: "NSW",
        city: "Chatswood"
    }
]};
```

[02] JSON :

```
{countries: [
    {
        name: "Australia",
        areas: [
            {
                 name: "NSW",
                 cities: [
                      {
                           name: "Gordon"
                      },
                      {
                           name: "Chatswood"
                      }
                 ]
            }
        ]
    } 
]}
```

Comment: I have not come across a library that would help you change the data structure the way you require. You may need to do it by hand (GSON can help significantly).

Comment: This has nothing to do with parsing, but is a remapping of a data structure into another.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer
I have tried to code the logic to be able to answer this question
and I solved this problem oddly.
the code that I made is not able to reuse for requirements.
so that I want more concise and elegant way to do.

Comment: There isn't anything in json that parallels what stylesheets (xslt) do in xml.

Comment: Have you considered the collection functions, especially `groupBy`, in [Underscore.JS](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're going to be doing a bunch of lookups I suggest using a collection of objects rather than your final structure with arrays.  You can then either convert it to the final structure or modify code to use it the way it is.

```
var countries = {};
for (var i=0, loc; loc = locations[i]; i++) {
    if (!countries[loc.country]) countries[loc.country] = {};
    if (!countries[loc.country][loc.area]) countries[loc.country][loc.area] = [];
    countries[loc.country][loc.area].push(loc.city);
}
alert(JSON.stringify(countries));
```

Comment: Wow!, I don't know why I didn't think of this idea.
Thank you James. I am happy now solving this problem, 
and I think, I can go home on today